# mysql-apt-config takes a verry long time to install on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

i'm trying to upgrade mysql from 5.6 to 5.7 using mysql-apt-config.
i've downloaded the deb and trying to install it.
but it 'hangs' on

```
Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.3.2-1ubuntu14.04) ...
```

and it stays there for hours. nothing happens.

could this be the issue?: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158052/how-to-configure-the-mysql-apt-repo-on-ubuntu-on-a-non-interactive-shell
that i'm not getting the selection menu, because i'm installing through SSH

Answer (score 1):

I suffered with the same problem and I found the solution at the [link that you mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158086/105566):

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
echo mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/enable-repo select mysql-5.6 | sudo debconf-set-selections
dpkg --configure -a
```

Don't forget to check your MySQL Version!

Thanks to you!